# OAuth1 (three legged): Invalid Signature

Tags: angular, oauth, ionic2

I'm having trouble configuring OAuth in my Ionic2 application. I do not use any framework/library for the front-end part of OAuth.

The problem is that I get a **`401: Unauthorized: Invalid signature`** every time I try to retrieve an access_token. (Scroll down for code, indented the problem with a comment)

Now my server is set up as a three-legged OAuth application [(as described fully here)](https://oauthbible.com/#oauth-10a-three-legged). This means there will be 3 endpoints:

### 1. `/request_token` (This one works)

Request (GET parameters):

```
oauth_version : ...
oauth_nonce: ....
oauth_timestamp: ...
oauth_consumer_key: ...
oauth_signature_method: ...
oauth_signature: ...
```

Response:

```
oauth_token: .... (temporary)
oauth_token_secret: ....
```

### 2. `/authorize` (This one works too -> opens up browser for authentication)

Request (GET parameters):

```
oauth_token: ....
oauth_callback: ....
```

Response

```
oauth_token: ....
oauth_verifier: ...
```

### 3. `/access_token` (this one doesn't work)

Request (GET parameters)

```
oauth_token: ....
oauth_verifier: ....
oauth_version : ...
oauth_nonce: ....
oauth_timestamp: ...
oauth_consumer_key: ...
oauth_signature_method: ...
oauth_signature: ...
```

Response:

```
oauth_token: .... (permanent)
oauth_secret: ....
```

---

The last one doesn't work although I set up the `signatureBaseString` the same way and set up the keys [according to the guide](https://oauthbible.com/#signed-requests)

Full code including the 2 other calls (messy yes I know)

> make it work, make it better, make it fast

Currently at 'make it work'

```js
login() {
    try{
        this.getRequestToken();
    }catch(err) {
        alert("ERROR: " + JSON.stringify(err));
    }

}

getRequestToken() {
    alert("in request token");
    let token_base_url = "https://servername/oauth/request_token";
    var oauth_nonce = this.generateNonce();
    var oauth_timestamp = this.getCurrentTimeStamp();

    let signatureBaseString = this.createSignatureBaseString(token_base_url, oauth_nonce, oauth_timestamp);
    let encryptedSignature = this.generateEncryptedSignature(signatureBaseString);

    let token_url = this.createOauthUrl(token_base_url, oauth_nonce, oauth_timestamp, encryptedSignature);

    this.http.get(token_url).subscribe(data => {
        this.doAuthorize(data);
    }, err => {
        alert("ups: " + JSON.stringify(err));
    });
}

doAuthorize(data: any) {
    alert("in do authorize");

    let responseParameters = data.text().split("&");
    let requestToken = responseParameters[0].split("=")[1];
    let requestTokenSecret = responseParameters[1].split("=")[1];

    let authorize_url = `https://servername/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=${requestToken}&oauth_callback=${encodeURIComponent('http://localhost/callback')}`;
    let ref = cordova.InAppBrowser.open(authorize_url, '_blank', 'location=yes');

    ref.addEventListener("loadstart", (event) => {
        // little workaround to make this work without actually having a callback url
        if((event.url).indexOf('http://localhost/callback') == 0) {
            ref.removeEventListener("exit", (event)=>{});
            ref.close();

            this.getAccessToken(event.url, requestTokenSecret, requestToken);
        }
    });
    ref.addEventListener("exit", (event) => {
        alert("closeseddd");
    });
}

getAccessToken(url:string, requestTokenSecret: string, requestToken: string) {
    alert("in get accesstoken");

    let access_token_base_url = "https://servername/oauth/access_token";
    var responseParameters = ((url).split("?")[1].split("&"));
    let authorizationToken = responseParameters[0].split("=")[1];
    let oauth_verifier = responseParameters[1].split("=")[1];

    let oauth_timestamp = this.getCurrentTimeStamp();
    let oauth_nonce = this.generateNonce();

    let signatureBaseString = this.createSignatureBaseString(access_token_base_url, oauth_nonce, oauth_timestamp, authorizationToken, oauth_verifier);
    let encryptedSignature = this.generateEncryptedSignature(signatureBaseString, requestTokenSecret);

    let access_token_url = this.createOauthUrl(access_token_base_url, oauth_nonce, oauth_timestamp, encryptedSignature, authorizationToken, oauth_verifier);

    this.http.get(access_token_url).subscribe(response => {
        alert(response.text());
    }, err => {
        alert("nooooo " + JSON.stringify(err));
    });
}

getCurrentTimeStamp(): number {
    return Math.round((new Date()).getTime()/1000.0);
}

generateNonce(): string {
    return Math.random().toString(36).replace(/[^a-z]/, '').substr(2);
}

createSignatureBaseString(url: string, nonce: string, timestamp: number, oauth_token?: string, oauth_verifier?: string): string {
    let baseString = "GET&" + encodeURIComponent(url) + "&";
    baseString += encodeURIComponent(`oauth_consumer_key=${this.oauth_consumer_key}&`);
    baseString += encodeURIComponent(`oauth_nonce=${nonce}&`);
    baseString += encodeURIComponent(`oauth_signature_method=${this.oauth_signature_method}&`);
    baseString += encodeURIComponent(`oauth_timestamp=${timestamp}&`);
    baseString += encodeURIComponent(`oauth_version=1.0`);

    if(oauth_token) {
        baseString += encodeURIComponent(`&oauth_token=${oauth_token}`);
    }

    if(oauth_verifier) {
        baseString += encodeURIComponent(`&oauth_verifier=${oauth_verifier}`);
    }

    alert("generated baseString: " + baseString);

    return baseString;
}

createOauthUrl(baseUrl: string, nonce: string, timestamp: number, signature: string, oauth_token?: string, oauth_verifier?: string): string {
    var url = `${baseUrl}?`;
    url += `oauth_consumer_key=${this.oauth_consumer_key}&`;
    url += `oauth_nonce=${nonce}&`;
    url += `oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&`;
    url += `oauth_timestamp=${timestamp}&`;
    url += `oauth_version=1.0&`;
    url += `oauth_signature=${signature}`;

    if(oauth_token) {
        url += `&oauth_token=${encodeURIComponent(oauth_token)}`;
    }

    if(oauth_verifier) {
        url += `&oauth_verifier=${encodeURIComponent(oauth_verifier)}`;
    }

    alert("generated url : " + url);

    return url;
}

generateEncryptedSignature(signatureBaseString: string, tokenSecret?: string): string {
    let secret_signing_key = this.oauth_consumer_secret + "&";

    if(tokenSecret) {
        secret_signing_key += tokenSecret;
    }

    let oauth_signature = CryptoJS.HmacSHA1(signatureBaseString, secret_signing_key);

    let encryptedSignature = encodeURIComponent(CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(oauth_signature));

    alert("Generated signature: "+ encryptedSignature + " with key: " + secret_signing_key);

    return encryptedSignature;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright so I don't know what the exact solution was anymore but now it works. It did have something to who with putting the basestring in alphabetic order.

These are the current functions I use for OAuth:

Create the basestring:

```
exampleUse() {
   let baseString = this.createSignatureBaseString('GET', 'someurl', 'asdfva323', '15134234234', localStore.getItem('token'));
}

createSignatureBaseString(method: string, url: string, nonce: string, timestamp: number, oauth_token?: string): string {
    let baseString = method+"&" + encodeURIComponent(url) + "&";
    baseString += encodeURIComponent(`oauth_consumer_key=${this.oauth_consumer_key}&`);
    baseString += encodeURIComponent(`oauth_nonce=${nonce}&`);
    baseString += encodeURIComponent(`oauth_signature_method=${this.oauth_signature_method}&`);
    baseString += encodeURIComponent(`oauth_timestamp=${timestamp}&`);
    if(oauth_token) {
        baseString += encodeURIComponent(`oauth_token=${oauth_token}&`);
    }
    baseString += encodeURIComponent(`oauth_version=1.0`);
    return baseString;
}
```

Create the encrypted signature:

```
exampleUse() {
  let baseString = ...
  let mySecret = thatthissolutiontookmetwomonths;
  let signature = this.generateEncryptedSignature(baseString, mySecret);
}

generateEncryptedSignature(signatureBaseString: string, tokenSecret?: string): string {
    let secret_signing_key = this.oauth_consumer_secret + "&";

    if(tokenSecret) {
        secret_signing_key += tokenSecret;
    }

    let oauth_signature = CryptoJS.HmacSHA1(signatureBaseString, secret_signing_key); 
    let encryptedSignature = encodeURIComponent(CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(oauth_signature));
    return encryptedSignature;
}
```

Create URL with the OAuth parameters (to get the access-token, etc.):

```
createOauthUrl(baseUrl: string, nonce: string, timestamp: number, signature: string, oauth_token?: string): string {
    var url = `${baseUrl}?`;
    url += `oauth_consumer_key=${this.oauth_consumer_key}&`;
    url += `oauth_nonce=${nonce}&`;
    url += `oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&`;
    url += `oauth_timestamp=${timestamp}&`;
    if(oauth_token) {
       url += `oauth_token=${oauth_token}&`;
    }
    url += `oauth_version=1.0&`;
    url += `oauth_signature=${signature}`;

    return url;
}
```

Create the Authorization header value **(neccessary on every authenticated request)**:

```
exampleUse(){
  let headerValue = this.getHeaderValue('POST', 'someserver');
  let headers = new Headers();
  headers.append('Authorization', headerValue);
  let options = new RequestOptions(headers);

  this.http.post(url, some_data, options).then(res => {...});
}    

getHeaderValue(method: string, url: string): string {
    let headerValue = 'OAuth ';

    //these functions not included but they're pretty straightforward
    let timestamp = this.getCurrentTimeStamp();
    let nonce = this.generateNonce();

    let token = localStorage.getItem("u:access_token");
    let secret = localStorage.getItem("u:access_token:s");

    let baseString;
    baseString = this.createSignatureBaseString(method, url, nonce, timestamp, token);

    let signature = this.generateEncryptedSignature(baseString, secret);
    headerValue += `oauth_consumer_key="${this.oauth_consumer_key}"`;
    headerValue += `,oauth_token="${token}"`;

    headerValue += `,oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1"`;
    headerValue += `,oauth_timestamp="${timestamp}"`;
    headerValue += `,oauth_nonce="${nonce}"`;
    headerValue += `,oauth_version="1.0"`;
    headerValue += `,oauth_signature="${signature}"`;

    return headerValue;
}
```

If anyone runs into any problems using the code I shared above, please let me know! I kinda feel like I've written a mini-library for this. Might even make it into one.